# Is there a way to manually provide virtual memory?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-memory

Virtual memory is disabled by the hoster in one of the Windows VServers I use to avoid heavy disk access. At the same time, the RAM provided is only 1GB, which is insufficient for an application I'm using.

I'm familiar with the RAM access pattern of this application, the CPU and RAM throughput is very low, but the amount of RAM required is large.

Is there a way to manually provide virtual memory to Windows so the application is able to run at all? From my point of view, anything is sufficient, be it from the local disk or via network (even though I think that it's getting perverted there).

Comment: You disabled virtual memory and you want virtual memory. Enable it again.

Answer (score 10):

I don't understand this question - you've disabled the page file (Which, to my knowledge, isn't recommended practice even in a virtual environment) and now you're asking how you can provide a page file?

Why don't you just re-enable the page file on this one server, and set the size manually?

Comment: Because I have no control over the page file, the hoster does.

Comment: @mafutrct Get more RAM or get them to enable Paging. Or rewrite the program to not use so much RAM, especially if it's all idle all the time.

Comment: @ChrisS: I wish I could - they already declined my inquiry. Rewriting the program is impossible, too. Only option left would be to pay for more RAM.

Comment: *Only option left would be to pay for more RAM* or terminate your contract with them and engage someone competent.

Comment: @mafutrct If you've not got the relevant access rights to re-enable the Page File, what kind of solution were you looking for? If you can't log on to the server then you're totally stuck regardless.

Comment: @DJPon3: I couldn't have put it better myself :)

Comment: @Dan: I can log in, I just can reliably run the application. What I'm looking for is something like a reverse RAM disk - but I'm not sure it's technically possible - or a workaround.

Comment: @mafutrct So why can't you enable the page file?

Comment: You do realize that even if you get the application to run, it will be slow right? Unless your app is reserving a gigabyte of zeros, chances are you'll start swapping very quick. The right solution when you don't have enough memory is to get more memory.

Comment: @Dan: I don't know how it's done technically, but the page file is  disabled and it's not possible to turn it on.

Comment: @gparent: It pretty much does precisely that. It just sits there and happily consumes memory :)

Comment: Can you not get the application's writer to fix it?

Comment: @gparent: No, its an unsupported legacy app (even though it has thousands of users). And honestly, it behaves pretty well considering the hard limit of only 1 GB system RAM.